# How to use GPS location in Django REST API?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, location, postgis

I am making a REST API with Django for a restaurant search app. I need to get a list of restaurants within a distance of X meters from my location. I am not sure how to store this on my database (I am using PostgreSQL) and how to retrieve this list.

I searched online some options and I found PostGIS as an extension to Postgres that can be used in Django, but I still want to listen to some of your recommendations.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want to use PostGIS extension in your database, and [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/) in your app.

Once you have that set up and configured, use a `PointField` in your model. Note that you want to extend from `django.contrib.gis.db.models.Model` now.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField()

Restaurant.objects.create(point=Point(lng, lat))
```

To query for your restaurants, create a `Point` object with your lat/lng (note that GEOS takes lat/lng parameters in lng, lat order). Then use the gis D measurement for your distance query. Here is a query for restaurants within 5000 meters:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

my_loc = Point(my_lng, my_lat)
Restaurant.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(my_loc, D(m=5000))
```

Comment: How to get current location of `User` ?

Comment: @Lars checkout [Django get Visitor's Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273590/django-get-visitors-location/58273922#58273922)